# jQuery Bootstrap - Reset form value on modal dismiss

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal that contains just one form field, however once the user enters this value it remains even when the modal is closed. I want it to reset on dismiss so that when the modal is opened again, the form is empty. I have some code for this already, however it's not working as it should. If anyone could help out it would be greatly appreciated.

HTML/Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModalViewAddress" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">View Hidden Information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Please enter authorisation code</p>
                <form id="auth_form10">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback" name="auth_code10" id="auth_code10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="auth_code_input10" autocomplete="new-password" name="auth_code_input10" type="password" required>
                        <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon" id="iconBad10"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <hr>

                <div id="modal-loader" style="display: none; text-align: center;">
                    <!-- AJAX loader -->
                    <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif">
                </div>

                <div id="dynamic-content-address" class="hidden">
                    <!-- Dyanamic address -->
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.myModalViewAddress').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).find('auth_form10')[0].reset();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/cLkekytx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues here. You were using `.myModalViewAddress` instead of `#myModalViewAddress`. Also you need to just clear the value with:

```
$('#myModalViewAddress').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#auth_form10 input').val('');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f78vg71a/)**

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now. Will accept as correct when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

after the onclick action:

```
$('#auth_code_input10').val() == null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is given because of your selectors.

if you want to reset your form elements you shold select your form by his id using `#` and then call the `.reset()` method.

also your event registration wasn't being made because you are using class selector `.` `$('.myModalViewAddress')` instead of id selector `#` `$('#myModalViewAddress')`

https://jsfiddle.net/cLkekytx/1/